# copy rows before updating them to preserve archive in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am experimenting with creating a table that keeps a version of every row. The idea is to be able to query for how the rows were at any point in time even if the query has JOINs. Consider a system where the primary resource is books, that is, books are queried for, and author info comes along for the ride

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    version INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (version > 0),
    author_name TEXT,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT '1',
    modified_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (author_id, version)
)

INSERT INTO authors (author_id, version, author_name) 
VALUES  (1, 1, 'John'),
        (2, 1, 'Jack'),
        (3, 1, 'Ernest');
```

I would like to be able to update the above like so

```
UPDATE authors SET author_name = 'Jack K' WHERE author_id = 1;
```

and end up with

```
2, 1, Jack, t, 2012-03-29 21:35:00
2, 2, Jack K, t, 2012-03-29 21:37:40
```

which I can then query with

```
SELECT author_name, modified_on 
FROM authors
WHERE 
author_id = 2 AND 
modified_on < '2012-03-29 21:37:00' 
ORDER BY version DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

to get

```
2, 1, Jack, t, 2012-03-29 21:35:00
```

Something like the following doesn't really work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION archive_authors() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $archive_author$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN

            -- The following fails because author_id,version PK already exists
            INSERT INTO authors (author_id, version, author_name)
            VALUES (OLD.author_id, OLD.version, OLD.author_name);

            UPDATE authors 
            SET version = OLD.version + 1
            WHERE 
                author_id = OLD.author_id AND 
                version = OLD.version;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$archive_author$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER archive_author
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON authors
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_authors();
```

How can I achieve the above? Or, is there a better way to accomplish this? Ideally, I would prefer to not create a shadow table to store the archived rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively easy to do with a BEFORE UPDATE trigger (instead of an AFTER UPDATE).

But that also means that you have to manually make sure that your archive trigger is triggered after all other BEFORE UPDATE triggers for that table.  Triggers are fired in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot come up with an alternative to your approach, maybe different execution but the base idea will IMO always be the same. If you want to be able to use he query you have shown above for querying a specific version, you have to stick to the single table and your posted trigger.

You *maybe* could also think about this: have a table `authors_revisions` that stores all revisions that you need (with a slightly changed trigger). So you original table will always have the most up-tp-date entries. You could than create a view that joins both your tables so you can perform the query you habe shown above. This way, your main table will not be cluttered with old versions.

Comment: Yes, I thought of a "<table>_versions" (authors is just an example for this thread). A pattern with a shadow table, however, would mean that I have to have a shadow table for every table that I want versioned. Seems messy, and unless a single table would bog Pg down in its speed, which it likely won't, a single table seems cleaner. still, and open to evaluating both patterns to find the best generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a trigger and do an insert in instead of an update:

```
insert into authors (author_id, version, author_name)
select 
    1, 
    (
        select max(version) + 1
        from authors
        where author_id = 1
    ),
    'Jack K'
```

BTW why have a version number if you have a timestamp?

Comment: Now that you put it that way, yes, you are correct... I could make a Primary Key out of (author_id, modified_on). But, using version allows "trivial" updates to a record, which will change the modified_on date, and would, in the absence of version, would make it into the latest record.

Comment: Right... doing a manual insert wrapped inside a transaction should do just as well. Hmmmm... Wonder why I decided to explore the TRIGGER route. Perhaps because it seems cleaner as it happens all by itself, without user intervention.

Comment: @punkish If it is a simple insert as above a transaction block is not necessary as the command is a transaction in itself